# Time and space efficient DataStructure for storing of a large data(order of 10^9) and accessing it quickly

Tags: data-structures, c++14

In competitive coding we generally need a DS such that say for some integer i in  the range of  (1< i < 10^9)(note: i need not all integer from 1 to 10^9, it can take some discrete interval values) we wanna store some its corresponding value , i.e a[i]= value; but we cant use array of size 10^9.

and if at all i use map concept, then find() (function for accessing my data )
will take logn time.

1) array is not space efficient and map are not time efficient in my application point of view.

Is there any better DS to do my above task ?
Any help is appreciated.
thanku :)

Comment: If your algorithm is too slow due to too many searches in an integer map, it's probably wrong. You could try `std::unordered_map`, but that probably won't help you much in your case. Other than that, there's not much you can do to optimize a map.

Comment: Turns out `std::unordered_map` for integers performs better than I thought.

Comment: You'll have to explain why map is not time efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unordered_map` is your buddy.

Unlike `std::map`, this offers amortized `O(1)` lookup and insertion time complexity. The underlying data-structure of `std::unordered_map` is hash table - bucket with separate chaining of doubly linked list holding the entries in usual case. On the other hand, `std::map` is balanced binary search tree under the hood offers logarithmic lookup.

For competitive programming, in today's online judges, `std::unordered_map` of five million entries will be fine. Anything beyond this can cause problem.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` has `O(1)` lookups *on average*, not amortized `O(1)`. There is a difference.